# When using Vim, how do you make it so that ALL your files you manipulate from now on will have 4-space tabs with vertical tab marks?

Tags: vim

I just recursively copied over a directory from a remote machine and would like to work on the files on my own computer.

However, whenever I used Vim remotely, every tab automatically did two things:

- used 4 spaces per tab
- put a vertical marking at the location of each tab to indicate that there was one

My own machine has *none* of these settings in place (I think each tab is about 8 spaces, and there are no vertical markings)

Is there a way to make it so that whenever I open up a file using Vim from now on, it will match the settings of the remote machine I originally developed the files on?

Answer (score 3):

Vim can display meta-characters that indicate tabs, eol (end-of-line) characters and such. To enable this just put the following in your `~/.vimrc` file:

```
set list
```

To set vim to use 4 spaces on tabs:

```
set tabstop=4
```

If you wish to have your tabs act as if you input four individual spaces, and a way to delete these as one tab, include:

```
set expandtab
set softtabstop=4
```

Or, if you're lazy like me, you simply copy the `~/.vimrc` file from your remote location to your home directory (note that it may use options or resources not available on your version etc.)

```
scp user@host.com:~/.vimrc ~/
```

Comment: I edited to add `scp remoteuser@example.com:~/.vimrc ~/.vimrc` since that explicitly answers the last question.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could supplement your files with [modelines](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#modeline), e.g. in comments:

```
vim: set list tabstop=4:
```

(Note that there has to be whitespace or a line beginning before the `vim:` keyword.)

This way, they will automatically display correctly on any system's vim. (Unless the [`'modeline'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27modeline%27) option is unset.)

Answer (score 0):

I use three options and put them in a comment at the end of my files (i.e. `modeline`):

```
// vim: ts=4 sw=4 et
```

That works great for my own projects. Other's projects, where you can't add a comment like so, I end up having to do it manually in most cases.

However, if you are sure you want such defaults everywhere, you can place them in your `~/.vimrc` file instead of each file. You can, of course, change the default with a comment in your files (i.e. your `Makefile` most certainly wants tabs, not spaces... at least in the old days, that was an issue).

I think that the `sw` option is super important otherwise shifting code for indentation is not going to work properly.

**Note:**

1. `ts` stands for `tabstop`
2. `sw` stands for `shiftwidth` (for the `<<` and `>>` commands), and
3. `et` stands for `expandtab` (i.e. use spaces, not a tab).